# Upvote for upvote in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

If a user asks for upvotes in the comments in Stack Overflow will it be considered as an **ABUSE?**

**CONTEXT:** A user answered my question and I accepted the answer but didn't upvote. Then they commented,

> "Consider upvoting if you found my answer helpful".

I was wondering if asking them (in the comments) to upvote my question in return to the upvote that I make in their answer, would be considered as an abuse.

Comment: Regarding the score of this question for anyone who might wonder: while this is a valid and productive discussion (meaning there are good answers that guide people in the right direction), it also implies using the discussed behavior, and that's the likely reasoning behind the low score.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Consider upvoting if you found my answer helpful

Even that is already problematic (as a comment, or as final sentence of a post). It's fine to educate new users about voting/accepting, but you are not a new user and [your profile shows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12980866/abhishek-choudhary?tab=topactivity) you're aware of how the voting functionality works. Comments are meant to [improve the post](/help/privileges/comment), not to earn more reputation. Similarly, when used in a post itself, it's fluff and it should be [edited out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/295232).

Asking for votes in return is even more problematic. Perhaps they already upvoted your question (I upvote most questions I provide an answer to; if the question deserves an answer, it's probably useful and clear enough to warrant an upvote).

Answer (score 9):

> I was wondering if asking him to upvote my question (in the comments) in return to the upvote that I make in his answer, would be considered as an abuse.

It is considered *extremely* poor etiquette and chances are you will find yourself getting downvotes. Upvotes should be for the quality of the post, not something to be traded for for other votes.

Pretty certain that on most sites (SO kinda has.... a bit of a massive number of flags), such comments would also be swiftly deleted.

Comment: Everything being equal (which means that the quality of the post itself could easily override this), I tend to downvote posts where somebody has asked either for an upvote or for an explanation for downvotes. Contrary to this, I will sometimes also upvote a post where somebody else has downvoted it (and provided a comment to that effect) for what I think is no good reason.